# Making forms visible when certain input field is selected

Tags: vba, image, excel, visible

so following issue: I have a map of a country with different postal code zones and if a postal zone is selected in a dropdown (in total two will be selected, departure and arrival more or less) then the picture referring to that postal zone should show up, otherwise it should stay hidden. I created a column where a 1 is typed in by formula if that region is selected and a 0 if that region is not selected.

So I have this now, which should go on for several times with all the postal codes:

```
Sub Test1()
If Range("AK10") = 1 Then
  ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("ES1")).Visible = msoTrue


End If

If Range("AK11") = 1 Then
  ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("ES2")).Visible = msoTrue


End If

End Sub
```

Somehow it does not work. Any ideas on that?

Edit: I now did it as a worksheet event to run but still does not work

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target = Range("AK10") = 1 Then
  ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("ES1")).Visible = msoTrue
    End With
    Target.Select

End If

 If Target = Range("AK11") = 1 Then
  ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("ES2")).Visible = msoTrue
    End With
    Target.Select

End If


 End Sub
```

Any further ideas?

Best 
Max

Comment: If you want to have this run automatically, you'll need to place it in a `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: Normally you'd refer to the shape by name or number, so either
Shapes("my map name"),visible = true   Or shapes(2).visible = true

Comment: Ok so I've done this now: see above

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to view some good tutorials about the basics of VBA and basic syntax. Also always indent your code correctly this makes it much easier to see issues. Nice formatted code is easier to understand and therefore leads to less issues. Especially beginners often consider nice looking code as unnecessary but it is a must have and the first thing you should learn: Nice code = less errors.

In this case you see that there is a `End With` were no `End With` should be, because there is no `With`.

Another thing is that *"… still does not work"* is the worst error description you can ever use. Instead **always describe** what happens or which error you get and where.

I suggest to test if the `Target` intersects with your `Range` and then test the value of that range.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AK10")) Is Nothing And Range("AK10").Value = 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("ES1")).Visible = msoTrue
        Target.Select
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AK11")) Is Nothing And Range("AK11").Value = 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("ES2")).Visible = msoTrue
        Target.Select
    End If
End Sub
```